# How to extend an 'in' test?

Tags: python

I usually test existence of a substring in a string via `in`:

```
In [3]: x = 'Hello World'

In [5]: 'rl' in x
Out[5]: True
```

**How can I extend this to test for the existence of one (or more) of several substrings in one string?**

I specifically would like to avoid using a chain of `or`:

```
In [6]: 'rl' in x or 'ld' in x
Out[6]: True
```

(the set of substrings will be variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `any`

```
any(i in x for i in ('rl', 'ld'))
```

*Example:*

```
>>> x = 'Hello World'
>>> any(i in x for i in ('rl', 'ld'))
True
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you. I did not think about combining a comprehension with `any`. (waiting for the acceptance timeout)

Comment: how did you answer a dupe after it has already been marked?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham :-) I started writing before he hammers..